# Converting div table to normal table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, export-to-excel

I was put on this project and the **other** developer before me used a bunch of `divs` to create a table. I was put in charge of exporting these tables to Excel. The only problem is that these aren't normal HTML tables. They are a bunch of `divs` made to look like a table.

Is there a way to convert the `div` table look alike to a normal HTML table? Or could I still export this look alike table to excel?

Here's a quick example

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add an example of one of these div tables to your question.

Comment: You could do a search and replace.  Or you could try copying the rendered HTML and pasting that directly into Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use JavaScript to create a `table`, loop through all the `.row` and `.column` elements in the `div` to popultate it, remove the `div` and append the `table`. Here's something I threw together very quickly to get you started. (I commented out the line that removes the `div` so you can see both in the results).

```js
var body=document.body,
    parent=body.querySelector(".table"),
    rows=parent.querySelectorAll(".row"),
    table=document.createElement("table"),
    tbody=document.createElement("tbody"),
    row=document.createElement("tr"),
    cell=document.createElement("td"),
    x=rows.length,
    cells=rows[0].querySelectorAll(".column"),
    y=cells.length,
    i,j;
table.appendChild(tbody)
for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    row=row.cloneNode(0);
    cells=rows[i].querySelectorAll(".column");
    y=cells.length;
    for(j=0;j<y;j++){
        cell=cell.cloneNode(0);
        cell.innerHTML=cells[j].innerHTML;
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(row);
}
body.appendChild(table);
//body.removeChild(parent);
```

```css
table{
    color:#f00;
}
.table{display:table;}
.row{display:table-row;}
.column{display:table-cell;}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
        <div class="column">Info</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To quickly format this as a table, use this CSS:

```css
div { display: table; }
div.row { display: table-row; }
div.column { display: table-cell; }
```

From there, you can style it however you need, or it should be copyable to Excel.

If you want to change the markup into a table, it's pretty easy. You'd just replace the outer `div` with a `table` tag, the `<div class="row">` elements with `tr` and the columns with `td`. Example follows.

```html
<table> <!-- was <div> -->
    <tr> <!-- was <div class="row"> -->
        <td> <!-- was <div class="column"> -->Info</td><!-- was </div> -->
        ...
    </tr> <!-- was </div> -->
</table> <!-- was </div> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to deal with this exact problem recently. The data in these divs is being populated from query results, I would suggest running another foreach loop this time properly inserting them in table cells. You could always set this table to display:none; if you dont want to display duplicates. Alternatively, I would set data-attributes to these divs such as data-row="1", data-column="2" etc., then manipulate them with javascript and inject them into a table. Once you have your desired data structure you can use [this plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-To-Convert-HTML-Table-To-CSV-tabletoCSV.html) to easily export the results to a CSV file.